# Where can I get a copy of my notice of disapproval from a failed checkride?

Tags: faa-regulations, pilot-certification, checkride

I can't find the notice of disapproval that I was given after I failed the oral portion of my private pilot checkride. I have looked EVERYWHERE.  What do I need to do?  Is there something on IACRA or can I go back to the examiner?

I am fairly close to taking the checkride again (I switched instructors), and I am under the impression that I need to take that paper with me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm, that could be an issue: [61.43 says](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp&r=PART&n=14y2.0.1.1.2#se14.2.61_143) "Presents to the examiner for the retest the **original** notice of disapproval form". I would call the FSDO and ask them, but there's a good chance you'll have to redo it.

Comment: Redo what exactly?

Comment: I assume the whole thing: without any record of which areas you passed the examiner can't give you any credit for what you did pass. But as @voretaq7 said in his answer, if you never got as far the flight test then you may not have accumulated any credit anyway.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I'm aware you can't pull the "completed" application from IACRA (with the examiner's notice of disapproval & failed areas on it). Much like with your knowledge test report you need to hang on to that original bit of paper.

I don't believe you *NEED* to bring the Notice Of Disapproval with you to a retest though.
61.43 says, in part:

> f) If a practical test is discontinued, the applicant is entitled credit for those areas of operation that were passed, but only if the applicant:
>   (1) Passes the remainder of the practical test within the 60-day period after the date the practical test was discontinued;
>   (2) Presents to the examiner for the retest the original notice of disapproval form or the letter of discontinuance form, as appropriate;
>   (3) Satisfactorily accomplishes any additional training needed and obtains the appropriate instructor endorsements, if additional training is required; and
>   (4) Presents to the examiner for the retest a properly completed and signed application.

So you only *need* it if you want to skip over the parts of the test you passed. If you don't have it, or your retest is more than 60 days after your original failed checkride, the examiner will have to give you a full exam, with no credit for the stuff you already completed.

---

Given that you failed the oral there's probably not much "credit for those areas of operation that were passed" you can claim, so it probably doesn't matter much that you lost the original notice of disapproval. You're almost certainly getting a "full checkride" anyway.

Comment: This is a correct interpretation. The examiner isn't even obligated to give credit for the previously completed elements, although they almost always do.